# Find the sum of the geometric series: $\;\sum_{k = 4}^\infty \frac 2{3^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the sum of the geometric series: $\quad \displaystyle \sum_{k = 4}^\infty \frac 2{3^k}$

I converted $\dfrac{2}{(3^k)}$ into $2(3^{-k})$ so since $|r|>1$ the series diverges so I can't find a sum.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $r=\frac{1}{3}$ here.

Comment: Do you know the formula for a geometric series?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: $\sum_{k=4}^{\infty}=\frac{2}{3^4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac13\right)^k$

Comment: if r=1/3, how do you get the answer to be 1/27? i know the formula for when k = 0 but k =4 in this case? a step by step approach would be really helpful

Comment: @Arjang When you edit a question, please don't make the title less informative than it originally was.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Title is meant to be summary, it was not less informative, Seriously What information was lost?

Answer (score 4):

This is a geometric progression with first term $\frac{2}{3^4}$ and common ratio $\frac{1}{3}$. Now simply apply the formula for such series.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty x^n=\frac{x^{n_0}}{1-x},\quad \forall x: |x|<1$$
so take $n_0=4$ and $x=\frac{1}{3}$ and multiply your result by $2$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, as noted in the comments, $r = \frac 13 \lt 1$:$$\sum_{k=4}^\infty\frac{2}{3^k} = 2\sum_{k=4}^\infty \left(\frac 13\right)^k $$

Now, knowing that $$\sum_{k=n_0}^\infty r^k=\frac{r^{n_0}}{1-r},\quad \forall r\;\text{such that}\; |r|<1$$ with $r = \frac 13$, gives us $$2\sum_{k=n_0}^\infty \left(\frac 13\right)^k=\frac{2\cdot 3^{4}}{1-\frac 13}$$

It's helpful to note that the sum for a geometric series with $k = n_0 = 0$, we have the sum you might be more familiar with: $$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k=\frac{r^{0}}{1-r} = \dfrac 1{1 - r}$$