# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}=\frac 13$ geometrically

Tags: sequences-and-series, visualization

As $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}$$ is a geometric series it is not hard to see that the result is $\frac 13$.

But how can this be seen by the following picture?
[image]

Comment: If the area of the triangle is 1 then you can see that at each level the section is split into 3 pieces with the same area. Hence if you take the limit you will fill $\frac 13$ of the area.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the sum of the geometric series: $\;\sum_{k = 4}^\infty \frac 2{3^k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465356/find-the-sum-of-the-geometric-series-sum-k-4-infty-frac-23k)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/4_%2B_1/16_%2B_1/64_%2B_1/256_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: Thanks for your support. It is not at all a duplicate btw.

Comment: This proof via picture is really nice. +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The big grey triangle is $\frac14$ of the big white, the second grey is $\frac14$ of the top white $\frac14$, etc.

On the other hand, the grey part is certainly $\frac13$ of all because we can combine each grey with the same-size white triangles to its left and right and these trapezoids tile the whole.